# How to replace a fragment in a FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I have a "main" fragment that contains tabs on the side, and when I click on any of those tabs, the ViewPager2 of the "main" fragment jumps to the specific fragment (each fragment is of a different class) in the FragmentStateAdapter.

Let's say that for one of those fragments, it has a button where if pressed, it replaces the current fragment in the FragmentStateAdapter, but the tabs are still at the side (we are still in the "main" fragment"). If I click on any of the tabs, I want it to work as before where it goes to the specific fragment.

I want to do this but I'm not sure how to do it or if it is the correct approach. Should I replace one of the fragments in the FragmentStateAdapter, or should I just destroy the ViewPager2 altogether and replace it with that desired fragment? Or is there a better approach?

This is how that FragmentStateAdapter looks like and I want to replace the EscortFragment when a button in it is clicked, with a different fragment.

```
public class HomeTabAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
    private Context context;

    public HomeTabAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle, Context context) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        this.context = context;
        fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new HomeFragment());
        fragments.add(new PurposeOfVisitFragment());
        fragments.add(new GalleryFragment());
        fragments.add(new EscortFragment());
        fragments.add(new MapsFragment());
        fragments.add(new FaqFragment());
        fragments.add(new SupportFragment());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, in your `HomeTabAdapter` class override `getItemId()` to generate a unique ID value for each of your fragments. Next time the base class `FragmentStateAdapter` needs to access the fragment, it will see a different ID value for that position. This will cause it to call `createFragment()` again for that position.

And if you override `getItemId()`, you must also override `containsItem()`.

So, for example, add the following to your `HomeTabAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
    long id = getIDForFragment(fragment);
    return id;
}

@Override
public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if (getIDForFragment(fragment) == itemId)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private long getIDForFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    // Insert code that generates a unique ID value for each Fragment here.
}

public void replaceFragment(int index, Fragment fragment) {
    fragments.set(index, fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Notice that the method `replaceFragment()` calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This forces to check ID values immediately, rather than waiting until some later time.

Comment: This is actually what I need since i use .set() in the arraylist.